# how to hover only parent li not children on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a simple example in which I added hover class on mouseover event.But the class is also added on children .I want hover class only add on parent Example (`a`,`b`,`c`).But not on `ab` and `cd`.But When I hover on `a` or first element it added hover class on on `ab` and `cd`.I just want to add hover class on parent mean only on `a`

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/qp6ex1jh/9/

```
$('#main-menu').on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" ); 
});
$('#main-menu').on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" ); 
});
```

Comment: do you really want to use event delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target only li elements which are not a descendant of an li like

```js
$('#main-menu').on("mouseenter", "li:not(li li)", function() {
   $(this).addClass("hover");
 });
 $('#main-menu').on("mouseleave", "li:not(li li)", function() {
   $(this).removeClass("hover");
 });
```

```css
#main-menu ul li.hover {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-menu">
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>a</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a>ab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>cd</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>c</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** Use only css like following:

```css
#main-menu >li:hover {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
    <ul  id="main-menu">
      <li>
        <a>a</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a>ab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>cd</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>c</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
</div>
```

Or By Jquery:

```js
$('#main-menu >li').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("hover")
});
```

```css
#main-menu li.hover{
  background-color:red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
  <section>
    <ul id="main-menu">
      <li>
        <a>a</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a>ab</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>cd</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>c</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
</div>
```